# Not able to install @angular/cli

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I am getting errors while installing anuglar cli. I am working on the system which I don't have admin rights to. So, I followed below link to install node & npm & correct node & npm version is displayed in command prompt.

[Install NodeJS & NPM without admin access](https://medium.com/@github.gkarthiks/how-to-install-nodejs-and-npm-in-non-admin-access-windows-machines-102fd461b54c)

[image: Error Image]

This is the error I am getting while installing angular cli. I have tried many options from previous SO answers but nothing worked. I have given explicit full control to the myself on  C:\NodeJS\NodeJS folder. What are the options now?

Comment: Did you have any cli instance running? try `taskkill /t /f /im node.exe` install, or restart your PC, try to uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: I tried to restart my PC every time I set the environment variable. Today also, I restarted my PC & first thing tried the angular cli install command. Still I got the same error & I haven't installed nodejs. Since I don't have admin rights, I have downloaded binaries.

Comment: You could try installing Angular CLI to a different location where you have access rights and set the PATH similar to NodeJS.

Comment: Run `npm cache clean --force` and try again

Comment: @MichaelD yes, I tried that too.

Comment: @penleychan yes. I have tried this option as well.

Comment: @MichaelD in the error screen, if you see the last line. It's showing C:\npm-global that's the different location I have set

Comment: Seems like you moved around the default path for node path? You would need to fix that folder path permission somehow

Comment: @penleychan yes, the NodeJS installation path is different & I have set the same in environment variables. Also, I have given full rights to myself on folder explicitly.

Comment: I mean go to the custom folder in cmd, and run the install command without the `-g` flag. And add the folder containing `ng` to PATH.

Comment: @MichaelD This I haven't tried. I will give a shot & update here.

Comment: @MichaelD This worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: I've posted the workaround as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One workaround would be to switch to a directory you have rights to and run the installation command without the `-g` flag.

```sh
C:\Users\user>cd C:\npm-global
C:\npm-global>npm cache clean --force
C:\npm-global>npm install @angular/cli
```

And add the `bin` folder of `node_modules` to the user environment variable `PATH`.

Comment: This worked. Thanks!